# Laravel 5.0 pass variable to middleware

Tags: laravel-5, middleware

At the moment I have to check if job record, which is being edited, belongs to right person. My get job edit route:

```
/user/job-edit/{slug}
```

So I created `JobEditMiddleware` but the problems is I can't access `{slug}` variable in my middlewar. Is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `segment()` method to retrieve various segments of your URI.

Try following in your middleware,

```
\Request::segment(3)
```

[Read More](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_segment)

Answer (score 1):

You can access to your slug parameter easier.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role) {
 //
}
```

You have to call your slug parameter like this :

```
$request->slug;
```

I think it's a better way than segment if you'll need to change your route later.