# Get route paramaters in middleware

Tags: validation, laravel, input, laravel-5, middleware

If my URL looks like `http://myapp.com/parameter1/value1/parameter2/value2`, how do I get these parameters and values in a custom middleware that is registered for the route?

I use Laravel's resource controllers for these. In my routes.php I have

```
Route::resource("a.b", "BController");
```

and in the controller's `__construct`:

```
$this->middleware("my.middleware", ["only" => ["show"]]);
```

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698245/laravel-5-0-pass-variable-to-middleware/31698478#31698478

Answer (score 0):

Multiple parameters can be set with a comma separated list like so

```
 Route::get('/admin',['middleware'=>'hasAccess:Admin,Registered', function () {
 return "Access is granted for this operation";
```

}]);